# What are the reasons for these strange user accounts in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

In my laptop (given from college), Windows 7 Professional 32-bit is installed. At the time of login, it asks for Username and Password to be entered into the respective fields. Each student has been given a Username and Password (different from another student). When I sign in into my account and type “net user” (without quotes) in cmd, it shows me 4 accounts (say A, B, C and Guest). My user account is not there in the list. How is it possible?

Also if I type “net user myusername”, it says “user name could not be found”, although I am logged in from that user account only (not from the above 4). Now how is this possible?

When I type in “net user username” with username as one of the four mentioned above (A, B, C and Guest), its details are shown with only B and C as Administrators. In the login screen, if I type A, B or Guest into the Username, the error comes saying something that the accounts do not exist. How is it possible that the account is visible in cmd but does not exist?

Comment: why have i been given -1. can i know this?

Comment: You're seeing the difference between domain users and local users

Comment: means what @SLaks ?

Comment: @SLaks please tell

Answer (score 1):

`net user` shows the local computer user accounts. When you login using as username and password you log into a domain user account. The reason these weird user accounts are there, is because they are used for system purposes.

The guest user account is used if the guest login feature is enabled, this user account will be reset when the user logs out. This account is also used as default account when a remote computer connects to a network share on your computer without a password

The administrator account is a hidden and deactivated account that has all administrative permissions. This account is often used to quickly recover a computer locked computer that has been locked by a forgotten password.